# code::blocks doesn't save workspace projects structure

Tags: codeblocks

I've started using C::B and found annoying issue: I usually have many open projects in the workspace and whenever I close C::B, upon next start I lose all my projects in the Projects tab. So every time I have to restore them from `File->Recent Projects` menu. Is there a better way to do it? I tried `File->Save Workspace`, `View->Perspectives->Save current` and nothing helps!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Environmental Settings -> General Settings and change the
"On Application Start-up" setting to "Open default workspace", then press OK.

When you close code::blocks it will ask to save changes to the workspace, press yes. Now when you start code::blocks it should still have all your projects open.